# Sqlite html5 Duplicating Records on Inserting

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, phonegap

I have a user log table, which inserts a record to every user action, but sometimes it duplicates the inserted records.

my code is very simple

```html
<script>
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tab_log (date_occurrence,hour_occurrence,number_user,occurrence,obs_occurrence) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [var_date, var_hour, var_number_user, var_occurrence, var_obs_occurrence]);
    
    });

  </script>

   <input type="button" name="btn_finish" id="btn_finish" value="Finish" onclick="this.blur();salvar();">
```

**EDIT** I have post full code. This code works perfectly, but sometimes doubles in the row of the log table

Has this ever happened to anyone? Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: Perhaps your are calling this piece of code twice. From where are your program calling this code?

Comment: It calls when the user clicks the button through `Onclick` but if it were this would happen every moment and only happens in 20% of the calls

Comment: Ok, can you share this part of code you described? Like, the html, the event bind, and the handler that calls the database insert so that people can try to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: I edit the question.. and add the ful code

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a click listener twice so to speak. There is a function `carregado()` which is called on `window` `load` event that binds an event listener to the `finish` button.

```
function carregado() {
    document.getElementById('btn_finish').addEventListener('click', salvar);
}
```

However, further on the `html` side, you are setting the `onclick` attribute of that button, making it call `salvar()` twice as `onclick` and `addEventListener('click')` both binds a different listeners to the button.

```
<input ... id="btn_finish" value="Finish" onclick="this.blur();salvar();">
```

What you can do to sort this out, is to remove the `onlick` attribute call to `salvar()` as it breaks your logic to bind the event only after finishing loading the page with `carregado()`, so the `onclick` part seems useless this case. Nevertheless, it will prevent the `salvar()` to be called twice.

Comment: Your help was very enlightening, I will redo my code and perform new tests